# Creating Azure Policy Issue

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm trying to create a policy that will audit my network interface in Azure.
the policy should point if the NIC has public IP assigned without NSG (on the NIC and not on the subnet)
this is my JSON. please assist to sort this out. currently, the issue here is that all NICs with/without PIP and NSG are non-compliant.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/networkSecurityGroup",
            "equals": "True"
          }
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress",
            "equals": "True"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using the `exists` condition operator.  The result would look something like this.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/networkSecurityGroup",
            "exists": true
          }
        },
        {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/ipConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress",
            "exists": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

The reason it marks all of yours as non-compliant is because neither the publiIpAddress or the NSG of the resources you are inspecting equals "True".  For more policy condition operators check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#conditions